# I want to incrementally backup my os to a copy: is this even practical?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, backup

I want to use redundancy to avoid problems in the case I accidentally brick my system.

I have one main drive and what I want to do is something like the following:

1. Have a small partition set aside for a minimal linux distro for maintenance (right now I'm checking out linux lite because it's based on Ubuntu, it has a GUI and a footprint of less than 10 GiB).
2. Set up one large partition for /home files, which will be shared.
3. Set up two partitions of the same size for two Ubuntu installations.
4. Use a boot manager to toggle between OS installations.
5. Log in to the minimal installation (linux lite) occasionally to perform some backup operation from my main Ubuntu installation to the clone, and hopefully incrementally, or restore as needed.

Having a minimal distro installed is obviously supposed to be a somewhat more convenient option than using a live usb instance.  Additionally, in the case I need to have a system up and running fast but my main OS is broken, I could easily switch to the back up system from the boot manager temporarily.

Would this feasibly work?  What problems would this cause or is there a better recommended strategy?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and [*official* flavors of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/desktop/flavours) are on-topic on this site.    Linux Lite maybe Ubuntu based; but it's not a Ubuntu system and is off-topic here.  If you're planning to share your home partition; you are aware & have explored the potential consequences with that decision (ie. potential data loss where different distributions using it are using different software versions that are incompatible due to changes!)

Comment: The "best" strategy is the one that you understand and can maintain. Only you can decide what is best for you. There are advantages to simplicity. There are advantages to complexity. Try your idea and see if it works for you.

Comment: Some folks have great success with shared /home directories Others find problems with versioned profiles -- common in some web browsers and email clients: an update to one OS will make your profile inaccessible to the other OS until the application updates to an equivalent version.

Comment: I have multiple Kubuntu installs. Mostly each version as released. I do not share /home, but do share all the data in a data partition. But like to have multiple drives and now have full installs on two external SSD, partially as backup & partially as emergency boot.

Comment: Reading this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408859/shared-home-causes-config-conflicts-between-ubuntu-and-debian-desktops/1408879 maybe useful (on sharing `/home`) ; but please note it's not really a distribution issue, but differences in software stack ages in my experience; in my answer I use `evolution` (a GNOME MUA app) as my example; but it's not my own app where I suffered issues or data loss.

Answer (score 0):

I would refrain from backing up the entire OS. It's much more important to keep the data you create and the configuration intact.

I generally use a tool called RSnapshot: https://rsnapshot.org/faq.html

It's been super stable and reliable on my server for ages.

It can be installed via apt: `sudo apt install rsnapshot`

It is used to create incremental backups of folders you want to have saved.
I would suggest you have a drive partition for snapshots (a separate drive would be better, an offsite-server would be even better, depending on how much you value the data you have, and on your internet connection).

To that, you set your `rsnapshot_root` (see `/etc/rsnapshot.conf`). You can then configure backup levels and run them via the terminal. (Realistically, you would use crontab for it, i.e. have a daily, weekly, monthly backup).

Most likely it would make sense to back up your `/home/<user>` folder, maybe also `/etc` (quite big sometimes). This has the advantage of not only being a replication, but it will also keep deleted or modified files in previous snapshots.

Should your OS die (for whatever reason), you can just reinstall the OS (which you would have to do anyway, more or less), and just copy in the configuration and data.

LightJack